# Buck regulator frequency

Tags: ground, buck, emc

I am trying to use a buck regulator. Usually I make it use at its Max frequency and then just use it. But now, we want to go for Emi and emc certification. I am hence told that this switching (a few hundreds of kHz) can generate noise in the system. So what is the optimal frequency to prevent rfi or noise ?

Comment: Radiation EMI is usually not an issue with a typical buck regulator when some care are taken. For conduction EMI, most likely, it is not any more difficult to deal with harmonics that start at 1MHz vs 500KHz, for example. So optimize the design around other parameters (cost, space ...). If you do need to add a filter in front, tune it to the particular frequency.

Comment: For conducted EMI look at http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snva489c/snva489c.pdf For layout tips (mostly related to radiated EMI): http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snva638a/snva638a.pdf I don't think your question asking for an "optimal frequency" has a simple answer. It depends on a components, layout etc. But I'm hardly an expert on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hundreds of khz is not your biggest problem. You should worry about hundreds of mhz that are involved in switch rise time, boost capacitor charging, etc. It all, by the way, starts with good layout, which if you don't have, is the reason for EMI problems.

There are several simple rules to follow, i hope not to miss something.

1. Keep magnetic flux as constant as you can: try making inductor current flow almost same way when the switch is on and off.
2. Where you have pulsed current, make sure return parh is right near the line. Of course, the both paths must be very short. Consider ferrite for boost cap to limit bandwidth.
3. Prevent capacitive coupling with switching node by removing plane underneath.

2 is most tricky, so pay close attention to whe pulsed currents flow. Use capacitors to provide the pulses, where needed, mostly on switch input.

By the way, you should also use a nice common mode filter on your input to prevent conductive emission.

Good luck!

Comment: Common mode ??? How does common mode filters come in regulators ? Where should it be connected ? Are u speaking of common mode chokes ? I thought common mode chokes are connected at output of differential drivers and such.

Comment: There are many common mode chokes and filters. What you need is in fact too filters around chokes. Use one choke for lower frequencies, with peak impedance around 50-500khz, and another with peak around 50-1000Ghz. On each side put capacitors between the choke ports and between each port and chassis. By the way, chassis, if you have it, is the most silent node, because of the thickness and hence very low impedance.

Comment: Could u please paste any app note if possible ?

Comment: Ah.. Well.. I write from my cellphone, so sorry, not today :) remind me tomorrow morning, i will post a picture.

Comment: Thaaaaank u so much

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that I'm a neophyte on EMI (and didn't [have to] get any products through certifications), but I've managed to find something in a [digikey article](http://www.digikey.com/en/articles/techzone/2015/feb/design-trade-offs-when-selecting-a-high-frequency-switching-regulator) narrowly but somewhat vaguely addressing your question:

> Another benefit of switching at a frequency as high as 4 MHz is that it enables designers to avoid critical noise-sensitive frequency bands, such as AM radio. However, there is a trade-off. For example, electromagnetic interference (EMI) can be problematic when operating at high-switching frequencies. EMI from a switching regulator is proportional to the square of the switching frequency – in other words, if the switching frequency doubles, the EMI can increase fourfold.

Hope this helps.

Also keep in mind that what continent[s] you want this certified on matters. From Maniktala's A-Z book, which I warmly recommend on practical issues like this:

> The FCC spectrum for digital equipment (currently) begins at 450 kHz, while the equivalent CISPR/EN regulations start at 150 kHz. So, FCC compliance can be
>   achieved with a relatively small and inexpensive filter. CISPR/EN Class A compliance often requires a filter with at least twice the volume of
>   the FCC-level unit. This filter can therefore be up to 50% more expensive. CISPR/EN Class B compliance can require a filter with 3-10 times the volume of the FCC unit, and could cost up to four times more.